# Make only 1 root file accessible, and serve it for all requests

Tags: nginx

I actually have this working, but I'd like to know if I am doing it the most efficient way, or if there are any improvements I can make to my conf file.  Here is what I am attempting to do:

1. If any file is requested from the root, we should always serve "index.html".  No other file should be accessible, and requesting anything else should be treated as if you requested "index.html".  Currently I'm using rewrite, but a redirect would be okay too, and possibly preferable.
2. Any file under "/css" or "/js" can be requested, and requesting files from those directories that don't exist should return a 404.

Here's my current working conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  client_max_body_size 50M;

  root /var/www/mysite;

  location = /index.html {
  }

  # map everything in base dir to one file
  location ~ ^/[^/]*$ {
    rewrite ^/[^/]*$ /index.html;
  }

  location ~ ^/css/ {
  }

  location ~ ^/js/ {
  }
}
```

### UPDATE

My final conf file, which is both faster under a load test and simpler than the original, is here:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  root /var/www/register;

  location = /index.html {
  }

  # Default location, request will fallback here if none other
  # location block matches
  location / {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.html redirect; # 'root' location '/'
  }

  location /css/ {
  }

  location /js/ {
  }

}
```

Comment: While your solution is technical correct, I would suggest to move everything but index.html (and /css/, /js/) out of /var/www/mysite. Nginx is a webserver and its job is so serve files to the network. Everything else is a hack ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got this right or not, but check this answer, you always want to server `index.html` so it should be the default location `location /`

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    root /var/www/mysite;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files index.html =404;
    }
    location /(css|js) {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  A couple things: the location directive won't work as written for the css/js part -- I believe you need to add regex matching with `~`, but I believe that's slower than my updated solution above.  The index directive isn't needed.  And just as a final note the try_files solution was about 100ms slower on average in my load test than the updated solution above.

Comment: oh yea, I forgot to add the regex part, and yea it's probably faster if i split them into two locations, but I always believed `try_files` is faster than rewrite, or at least that's how they always say in the docs..

Comment: Sorry, I believe try_files is faster than rewrite -- but for the majority of requests neither will be happening, that is, index.html will be the file requested.  I should have clarified that in the OP.  So anyway I am optimizing speed for the most common types of requests.